# Lion Server with Profile Manager

Tags: server.app, profile-manager

I setup a few profiles in the profile manager and when I remove them from the profile they still seem to be applied on the clients. Like to test around I made a change to the dock size and then un-applied it so it isn't even listed but yet the client cannot change their dock size anymore.

How do I completely revert a change made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the profile from the client system preference pane.